# how to get return data from mysql connection check callback function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I can not get return data from mysql connection check function at nodejs. Output is always false.

```
var dbcheck = false;

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if(err) {

        dialog.showMessageBox(null,dbOptions, function (response) {

            if(response == 1){
                shell.openExternal("https://innoscript.co");
                app.quit();
            }

            if(response == 0){ app.quit(); }
        });
    }

    if(!err){
        dbcheck = true;
        return dbcheck;
    }

});

console.log(dbcheck);
```

Comment: `connection.connect()` is asynchronous, so your `console.log(dbcheck);` runs first, then the rest of the code runs.

Comment: Yup, because of Async Nature console.log is printing the result without actually db connection code getting executed first.

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log() is executed before the connection takes place.

You should console.log() inside the callback function.